# Modal always open with the last value of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, material-ui, modal-dialog

For example, I have an array of objects. I am trying to show every object's value in several cards. All values are shown properly. But I am trying to show value in the modal using button click. Unfortunately, every time I click the indiabudal button, the modal shows the last object value on it.

```
<Grid Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }} >
                {
                    postData.posts.map((book) =>
                        <Grid>
                            <Card >
                                <CardMedia
                                    component="img"
                                    height="240"
                                    image={`${book.url}`}
                                    alt="green iguana"
                                />
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                                        {book.title}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography>
                                        {book.author}
                                    </Typography>
                                    
                                </CardContent>

                                <CardActions>
                                    <Button >Buy Now</Button>
                                    <div>
                                        <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
                                        <Modal
                                            open={open}
                                            onClose={handleClose}
                                            aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
                                            aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
                                        >
                                            <Box sx={style}>
                                            
                                                <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                                                    {book.title}
                                                </Typography>
                                                <Typography>{book.author}</Typography>
                                                <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                                                    {book.detail}
                                                </Typography>
                                                <Rating name="size-medium" defaultValue={`${book.rating}`} />
                                            </Box>
                                        </Modal>
                                    </div>
                                </CardActions>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    )
                }
            </Grid>
```

Comment: I guess that every modal opens at once, but you don't see the other once because they are behind the last one.

Answer (score 1):

### What is happening

Apparently you are using a single state for showing and managing your modals. Something like this:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const handleOpen = () => {
  setOpen(true);
};
const handleClose = () => {
  setOpen(false);
};
```

This will work if you have **One** modal, but for managing an **array** of data _ each one having its own modal, this approach is not enough.
Because no matter which object's button you click, the `open` value will be set to `true` and all the modals will open at the same time on top of each other.
As a result you would see the last item's modal because it's the uppermost.

### Solution

Bring out `Modal` element from the `map` function. You only need one Modal, but the data inside that modal needs to be according to the clicked card. So we also need a `selectedBook` state to know which item has been selected.

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const [selectedBook, setSelectedBook] = React.useState(null);

const handleOpen = (book) => {
  setOpen(true);
  setSelectedBook(book);
};

const handleClose = () => {
  setOpen(false);
  setSelectedBook(null);
};

<>
  <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }}>
    {postData.posts.map((book) => (
      <Grid key={book.url}>
        <Card>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="240"
            image={`${book.url}`}
            alt="green iguana"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
              {book.title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography>{book.author}</Typography>
          </CardContent>

          <CardActions>
            <Button>Buy Now</Button>
            <div>
              <Button onClick={() => handleOpen(book)}>Open modal</Button>
            </div>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
  <Modal
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
    aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
  >
    <Box sx={style}>
      <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
        {selectedBook.title}
      </Typography>
      <Typography>{selectedBook.author}</Typography>
      <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
        {selectedBook.detail}
      </Typography>
      <Rating name="size-medium" defaultValue={`${selectedBook.rating}`} />
    </Box>
  </Modal>
</>
```